# how transfer the data from mongodb to elascticsearch with logstash 2.2.0?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, logstash

the problem is that logstash 2.2.0 are not compatible with the plugin **logstash-input-mongodb** and don't find other way to transfer the data.
There are a tool like import-handler of solr?

Comment: How its possible upgrade the puglin for will be compatible with my logstash?

Comment: The latest version of the plugin, 0.3.3, works with logstash 2.2.0

Answer (score 0):

We use Mongo-Connector to transfer data from mongo to elastic: https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector

Comment: But this tool are not flexible for introduce any change.